# How to I set different colors to subsets of line plot iterations in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors, iteration

I am iteratively plotting the `np.exp` results of 12 rows of data from a 2D array `(12,5000)`, `out_array`. All data share the same x values, (`x_d`). I want the first 4 iterations to all plot as the same color, the next 4 to be a different color, and next 4 a different color...such that I have 3 different colors each corresponding to the 1st-4th, 5th-8th, and 9th-12th iterations respectively. In the end, it would also be nice to define these sets with their corresponding colors in a legend.

I have researched `cycler` (https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/color_cycle_demo.html), but I can't figure out how to assign colors into sets of iterations > 1. (i.e. 4 in my case).  As you can see in my code example, I can have all 12 lines plotted with different (default) colors -or- I know how to make them all the same color (i.e. `...,color = 'r',...`)

```
plt.figure()
for i in range(out_array.shape[0]):
    plt.plot(x_d, np.exp(out_array[i]),linewidth = 1, alpha = 0.6)
plt.xlim(-2,3)
```

I expect a plot like this, only with a total of 3 different colors, each corresponding to the chunks of iterations described above.
[image: 12 lines all with different colors]

Comment: Can't you just use a while loop using a comparator with your idx/4 ? and apply different color if the result is 1, 2, 3

Comment: Hi Clément. I am a novice programmer. If you think it will work, I will try it. Any chance you could show an example or suggest new lines in the existing code?

Comment: I am a beginner too, but the idea is exactly the same than your single color case. Just add the **if** case in your for loop, divide your NBR_OF_CURVES by NBR_OF_CHUNKS, you will have a chunk index which can be used to pick up color in a preset color array. Probably not the best pythonicway to do that but this is how i would do that.  PS : forget the while loop of the first comment I wanted to say if case

Comment: This seems like good logic. How should I count number of curves iteratively?

Comment: isn't it your for loop iterator

Comment: Thanks Clement. Your insights led me to the answer, which I posted below.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196969/discussion-between-clement-and-celder88).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An other solution**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)

color = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'p']

for i in range(12):

    plt.plot(x, i*x, color[i//4])

plt.show()
```

Comment: You should rewrite a question since it is not the same problem for SO website clarity purpose.

Answer (score 1):

```
plt.figure()
n = 0
color = ['r','g','b']
for i in range(out_array.shape[0]):
    n = n+1
    if n/4 <= 1:
        c = 1
    elif n/4 >1 and n/4 <= 2:
        c = 2
    elif n/4 >2:
        c = 3
    else:
        print(n)
    plt.plot(x_d, np.exp(out_array[i]),color = color[c-1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Any thoughts on how I would create a legend for the 3 subsets of iterations (`c = 1, c = 2, c = 3`)? The titles should be 0-45, 5-45, 10-45 respectively.